# How do I customize the header and title of an Excel sheet generated by a Foundry Slate export button?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-slate

I'm using an Export button to create an Excel spreadsheet with the results of a Foundry Slate query, but I'd like the name of the resulting file to be something other than "q_myQuery.xlsx".

How can I customize the filename and column headers of the resulting file?

Answer (score 0):

In Slate you can export from a query or from a function - in either case, the name of the query or function will be the name of the output file, and the header column will be the name of the property or column. If you need to export a query but want to change these names, piping it through a function, then exporting the function instead is the best approach.